# Laravel Error: Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance. Yet it works on the local server

Tags: php, laravel, collections, eloquent

As mentioned in the title I get the error `"Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance."` Only when I run the code online here are my relevant codes.

1-EmployeeController (browser tells me that the error is here the second line)

```
public function show(Employee $employee)
{
    $employee = Employee::find ($employee);
    $edocument = EDocument::where ('employee_id',$employee->id)->first();
    return view ('employee.show')->withEmployee($employee)->withEdocument($edocument);
}
```

2-show.blade.php

```
<div class="jumbotron">
<h1>{{$employee->name}} ({{$employee->position}})</h1>
@if (isset($edocument))
    <a href="{{route('employee-docs.show',$edocument->id)}}" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Go To Employee Database Page</a>
@else 
    <p class="lead bg-danger">Employee documents are not uploaded</p>
@endif
<a href="{{route('getContract',$employee->id)}}" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Create Employee Contract </a>
```

if anyone can explain to me this error in more details that would be great also. thanks

ps.. this is my first laravel project (;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use route model binding in your controller method to get the `Employee` model. But you also run a `find`, which would fail since you're passing the model instead of the id. Do as one of the codes shown below and don't mix them.

Do this if you want to use route model binding.

```
public function show(Employee $employee)
{
    $edocument = EDocument::where ('employee_id', $employee->id)->first();

    return view ('employee.show')->with(compact('employee', 'edocument'));
}
```

Do this if you want to pass the employee id and fetch the model in controller.

```
public function show($employee)
{
    $employee = Employee::find($employee);
    $edocument = EDocument::where ('employee_id', $employee->id)->first();

    return view ('employee.show')->with(compact('employee', 'edocument'));
}
```

Comment: thanks. yea I did that and it worked ... I guess I didn't notice that error because the code somehow worked locally which was weird.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you.  Why don't you pass the information in the controller using -

```
return view('employee.show', ['employee' => $employee, 'edocument'=>$edocument]);
```

It worked for me.  (Do not have to change anything in the show.blade .php)